# Type mismatch on throw line in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

Please help me understand the following error in Kotlin: I have the following function

```
fun getSomething(): Something {
    return loginContext.user()?.let {
        // user is logged in
        return Something()
    } ?: {
        // user is not logged in
        throw UnauthorizedException()
    }
}
```

and IntelliJ tells me

```
Type mismatch.
Required: Something
Found: () → Nothing
```

Coming from Java I find this a bit confusing because when I throw an exception there is nothing to return. How can there be a type mismatch?

Comment: don't you need `?: run` for this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you may write it like this (using expression body)

```
fun getSomething(): Something = loginContext.user()
    ?.let { Something() }
    ?: throw UnauthorizedException()
```

Comment: Ahaa! So the trick is to not use `{` and `}`. Thank you :-)

Comment: @EthanLeroy `{ }` denotes a lambda-function in Kotlin (at least when used like you did above). You either remove the braces when you have a single expression, or you use the `run`-function to run a block of code.

Comment: Braces do seem to be a source of confusion… In Kotlin, braces always define a lambda _except_ for a few special cases (such as `if` branches, `for` and `do`/`while` loop bodies, and `try`/`catch`/`finally` blocks) — but those special cases are very common, and very familiar from other languages, so it's easy to miss that they _are_ special cases! As marstran says, anywhere else you want a block you can just use `run { /*…*/ }`.

Comment: Is there a difference between `?: run { something() }` and just `?: something()`?